# docker mysql container exits after being started

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to launch a docker MySQL container with an initialization script. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:11
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY . .
RUN npm install
ENV PORT=8000
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And I have my init.sql file in two places, the home directory as well as the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ folder. The init.sql file only has create table and insert statements. I'm running my Docker commands in this order:

```
//start network
docker network create --driver bridge mysql-net

//launch docker mysql container with init script to create tables & data
docker run -d --name mysql-server --network mysql-net -p 3306:3306 -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword" -e "MYSQL_DATABASE=yelplikeapp" -e "MYSQL_USER=yelplikeapp" -e "MYSQL_PASSWORD=hunter2" -v "/c/Users/marti/Documents/projectFolder:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" mysql:5
```

launching the mysql-server container works initially, but after a couple seconds when I run 'docker ps -a'I can see that it exits as soon as it starts:

[image]

Why is my mysql-server container exiting? I've been trying to go into the container and view the database to verify that all the tables were created successfully. But I was having trouble doing that and think that this is the root of the problem.

For transparencies sake I'll post my full init.sql file:
When I check the logs for mysql-server, there's an error message saying 
ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1: Table 'users' already exists

```
drop database yelplikeapp;
create database yelplikeapp;
use yelplikeapp;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS businesses;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS photos;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reviews;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO users(id, username) VALUES 
( NULL, 'brungoTungis' ),
( NULL, 'kramer' ),
( NULL, 'elaine');

CREATE TABLE businesses (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ownerid MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  state VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  zip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  phone VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  subcategory VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  website VARCHAR(255),
  email VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (ownerid) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO businesses(id, ownerid, name, address, city, state, zip, phone, category, subcategory, website, email) VALUES ( NULL, 1, 'taco bell', '1157th ave nw', 'corvallis', 'or', '98023', '423-232-1313', 'fastfood', 'mexican', 'www.tacobell.com', 'tacobell@gmail.gov' ), ( NULL,  1, 'kfc', '1158th ave nw', 'seattle', 'wa', '98223', '423-232-993', 'fastfood', 'chicken', NULL, NULL );

CREATE TABLE photos (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userid MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  businessid MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  caption VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (businessid) REFERENCES businesses(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO photos(id, userid, businessid, caption) VALUES 
( NULL, 2, 1, 'coolcaption' ),
( NULL, 3, 2, NULL ),
( NULL, 3, 1, 'badcaption');

CREATE TABLE reviews (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userid MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  businessid MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  dollars MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  stars MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  review VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (businessid) REFERENCES businesses(id)
);

INSERT INTO reviews(id, userid, businessid, dollars, stars, review) VALUES 
( NULL, 2, 1, 2, 3, 'mycoolreview' ), ( NULL, 1, 2, 2, 3, NULL );
```

Comment: You may try to do "docker logs CONTAINER_ID" to check what failed on MySql container.

Comment: Your SQL is certainly not an issue

Comment: @ŁukaszGawron checked the logs and found and error saying 'users table already existed', going to try and add 'drop table if exists;' statements to my sqlfile before every create table and re-build my mysql-server container

Comment: Not sure why you are copying SQL script to this node container in Dockerfile you provide. Could you explain that?

Comment: @ŁukaszGawron I thought that was needed in order to copy my init.sql file into the mysql-server container. Also I updated my post with my new sql code. Even after running it without that copy command I'm still getting a 'users table already exists' error

Comment: You need to tell it to use your database, MySQL defaults to mysql database. Add `USE mydbname;` to the top of your SQL.

Comment: @miken32 i edited my sql file to include dropping and recreating the table, then USEing it at the very top of the file. removing the copy statement from my dockerfile didnt seem to make a different either, i just keep getting the same error message:  ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1: Table 'users' already exists

Comment: As I understand you are running standard mysql:5 container, which is not what you are defining in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

solved it, i removed the copy statement from my dockerfile, and also deleted on of my init.sql files.I had two in my project files, one in my homeRepo/init.sql  and homeRepo/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

I deleted the homeRepo/init.sql file, re - ran the creation of my docker mysql-server creation, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Run the "getenforce" command. If the output says "enforcing", run the command "setenforce 0".